# SPFILE invalid after being edited in Windows

Tags: oracle

I was attempting to fix another issue and set sec_case_sensitive_logon to false. I then removed this using Notepad++ instead of the CLI. But I then started getting various errors:

[image]

When I attempt to run `startup`,  I get the following error:

[image]

I have no idea why it was trying to use the init ora file because I've started this DB fine in the past and this file doesn't exist.

I attempted to create a new PFILE from the existing SPFILE:
[image]

So my only conclusion is this must have been from when I updated my SPFILE using Notepad++. But the line endings are correctly showing as LF.

I'm not sure what could be happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find an existing PFILE in `..\product\18.0.0\admin\XE\pfile\`. I then recreated my SPFILE using `CREATE SPFILE='PATH_TO_NEW_SPFILE' FROM PFILE='PATH_TO_PFILE'` and started my server using `STARTUP PFILE='PATH_TO_PFILE'`.

Comment: Just to expand a bit, the spfile is a binary file -- in spite of the fact that _MOST_ of the context appears to be clear text.  Binary information in the file header includes a checksum of the file.  So when you edit it directly with a text editor, you render the binary information, and by extension the entire file,  invalid.

Answer (score 2):

**Never edit the spfile directly!** spfile settings should only be updated from SQL*Plus or SQLcl using `alter system ... scope=spfile` commands. The file format is *not* plain text and should never be edited directly.

If you must edit the config file, use the `create pfile from spfile` command to create a backup copy (be careful not to overwrite the *original* pfile, which may contain other info like a pointer to the spfile), edit the pfile copy, then use `create spfile from pfile` command to recreate the spfile with the changes from your pfile copy.